# how to properly sequence the update on variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is the program I have created. Because of some limitations I have to use the setInterval funcation. I want to set value value to true only if all 3 select statement don't return any value aka all the valCheck var should be false.

Issue, because of the sequence of the select elements, the values are not set properly.

Can someone correct me what I am doing wrong here?

Program ---->

```
var valCheck1 = false;

var valCheck2 = false;

var valCheck3 = false;

$("#check_dedupe").on("click", function() {

    console.log("button clicked");

    console.log("valcheck1.s--->" + valCheck1);
    console.log("valcheck2.s--->" + valCheck2);
    console.log("valcheck3.s--->" + valCheck3);

    //automatically trigger click event for “Salesforce select" element we have added on to the form
    //Salesforce Select Contact(Grower)
    $('#component-9193-6efe-0931 .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function() {
        //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
        var s = setInterval(function() {
            //check if there are records received from Salesforce
            if ($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0) {
                //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
                $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
                console.log("valcheck1.1--->" + valCheck1);
                valCheck1 = true;
                console.log("valcheck1.2--->" + valCheck1);
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
            } else {
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
                //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
                $('#component-9193-6efe-0931 .modal.fade.in').hide();
            }
        }, 2000)
    }).trigger('click');

    //Salesforce Select Contact(Not Grower)
    $('#component-803b-9296-e785 .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function() {
        //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
        var s = setInterval(function() {
            //check if there are records received from Salesforce
            if ($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0) {
                //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
                $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
                console.log("valcheck2.1--->" + valCheck2);
                valCheck2 = true;
                console.log("valcheck2.2--->" + valCheck2);
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
            } else {
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
                //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
                $('#component-803b-9296-e785 .modal.fade.in').hide();
            }
        }, 2000)
    }).trigger('click');

    //Salesforce Select Lead(Global Lead)
    $('#component-094e-ec71-09ff .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function() {
        //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
        var s = setInterval(function() {
            //check if there are records received from Salesforce
            if ($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0) {
                //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
                $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
                console.log("valcheck3.1--->" + valCheck3);
                valCheck3 = true;
                console.log("valcheck3.2--->" + valCheck3);
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
            } else {
                //End the Interval, this will exit the function
                clearInterval(s);
                //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
                $('#component-094e-ec71-09ff .modal.fade.in').hide();
            }
        }, 2000)
    }).trigger('click');


    if (valCheck1 === false && valCheck2 === false && valCheck3 === false) {
        console.log("valcheck1.f--->" + valCheck1);
        console.log("valcheck2.f--->" + valCheck2);
        console.log("valcheck3.f--->" + valCheck3);

        window.formyoula.form_fields["ef95-ac8a-1158"].set("value", true);
    }

    //$('.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block.finish').click(function(){
    //  console.log("submit action button clicked");
    //}).trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the accepted or not. But I tried adding the interval for the check and update also and the functionality is working as expected.

If still, the code needs to be updated to meet the standards, please do let me know guys.

Thanks

Here is the code----------

```js
var valCheck1 = false;
var valCheck2 = false;


$("#check_dedupe").on("click", function(){
  console.log("button clicked");
  
  console.log("valcheck1.s--->" + valCheck1);
  console.log("valcheck2.s--->" + valCheck2);
  
  //automatically trigger click event for “Salesforce select" element we have added on to the form
  //Salesforce Select Contact(Grower)
  $('#component-9193-6efe-0931 .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function(){
    //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
    var s1 = setInterval(function(){
      //check if there are records received from Salesforce
      if($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0  ) {
        //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
        $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
  console.log("valcheck1.1--->" + valCheck1);
  valCheck1 = true;
  console.log("valcheck1.2--->" + valCheck1);
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s1);
      }else{
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s1);
        //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
        $('#component-9193-6efe-0931 .modal.fade.in').hide();
      }
    },2000)
  }).trigger('click');
  
  //Salesforce Select Contact(Not Grower)
  $('#component-803b-9296-e785 .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function(){
    //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
    var s2 = setInterval(function(){
      //check if there are records received from Salesforce
      if($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0  ) {
        //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
        $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
  console.log("valcheck2.1--->" + valCheck2);
  valCheck2 = true;
  console.log("valcheck2.2--->" + valCheck2);
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s2);
      }else{
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s2);
        //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
        $('#component-803b-9296-e785 .modal.fade.in').hide();
  }
    },2000)
  }).trigger('click');
  
  //Salesforce Select Lead(Global Lead)
  $('#component-094e-ec71-09ff .lookup_salesforce_record').click(function(){
    //set an Interval to wait for the records to be retrieved from Salesforce.
    var s3 = setInterval(function(){
      //check if there are records received from Salesforce
      if($('.select_salesforce_record').length > 0  ) {
        //Select the first record received, the assumption here is that data on Salesforce is cleansed and no duplicate contacts exists based on email. If not we select the first record from the list of records received from Salesforce.
        $('.select_salesforce_record').first().click();
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s3);
      }else{
        //End the Interval, this will exit the function
        clearInterval(s3);
        //Hide the popup model which will be opened from previous code
        $('#component-094e-ec71-09ff .modal.fade.in').hide();
      }
    },2000)
  }).trigger('click');
  
  var s4 = setInterval(function(){
   
 if(valCheck1 === false && valCheck2 === false){
  console.log("valcheck1.f--->" + valCheck1);
  console.log("valcheck2.f--->" + valCheck2);
  
   window.formyoula.form_fields["ef95-ac8a-1158"].set("value", true);
   clearInterval(s4);
  }
   
    },2000);
 

 
  //$('.btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block.finish').click(function(){
  //console.log("submit action button clicked");
  //}).trigger('click');
  
});
```